# check website url status using powershell version 2.0

Tags: powershell-2.0

I need to check if URL is working properly or not using "PowerShell Version 2.0"
I found this script over internet, but it is not wokring fine for wrong URL's. It should go in `else` loop for wrong URL's as well as print website code. And I am not able to pass credentials in this script.

e.g. for `www.google.com`(correct URL) status code should be `200`but 
for `www.gfjgugy79rt9`(Wrong URL) status code should be something like `404`

script I found over internet for powershell version 2.0:

```
# First we create the request.
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://google.com')

# We then get a response from the site.
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

# We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
    Write-Host "Site is OK!" 
}
Else {
    Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
}

# Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.
$HTTP_Response.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell  higher than 2.0 you should use `try ... catch ... finally` because this code fire exception when the URI is no conform or when the adress part is not solvable by the DNS :

```
try {
  # First we create the request.
  $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://google.com')

  # We then get a response from the site.
  $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

  # We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
  $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

  If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
      Write-Host "Site is OK!" 
  }
  Else {
    Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
  }
}
catch {
  Write-Verbose $_.ScriptStackTrace
  Write-Verbose "Ligne $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber) : $($_.exception.message)"
}
finally {
  # Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.
  $HTTP_Response.Close()
}
```

In PowShell 2.0 you just have to put a `Trap` code at the beginnig of the scope (function, script) where you want to catch these exception :

```
trap
{
  Write-Verbose $_.ScriptStackTrace
  Write-Verbose "Ligne $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber) : $($_.exception.message)"
  Write-Verbose ([datetime]::Now)
  return
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can I use it for multiple URL's ? For example putting all URL's in a text file and retrieving through for loop. I tried this for multiple URL's but could not succeeded.

Comment: You can put this code into a function abd loop calling this function.